# PHP array in mySQL query: "Unknown column"

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I cannot figure out what's wrong with my query.

I'm trying to use a PHP array in it.

Array:

```
$devices2 = implode(", ", $devices);
//echo $devices2 result: BlåAvformning, GulAvformning
```

SQL

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table
          WHERE myColum IN($devices2)";
```

Error:

> Unknown column 'BlåAvformning' in 'where clause'

I have tried adding quotes, and searched several likely questions, but I cannot get this to work!

Why?

**UPDATE**

As commented I needed more quotes:

```
$devices2 = "'".implode("', '", $devices)."'";
```

Comment: In SQL, string values need to be quoted: `$devices2 = "'" . implode("', '", $devices) . "'";`..... though in 2016, you really should be using bind variables

Comment: @MarkBaker You can set this as an answear! What is bind variables?

Comment: [Prepared statements and bind variables](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Agree with @MarkBaker, should mark it as the answer

Comment: It seems that the problem is the name of your column (myColum) and not the values in $devices2. Is the name of your column BlåAvformning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, i needed more qutoes:

```
$devices2 = "'".implode("', '", $devices)."'";
```

Credit to: Mark Baker